# Raspberry Pi v2 pin P1-12 function at power-up

Tags: hardware, raspberry-pi

1. Are all pins set to Alternate Function Mode 0 when the board powers-up?
2. If question 1 is true, then what function is set on header P1, pin 12?  BCM2865 ARM Peripherals.pdf Table 6-31 indicates pin 12 in alt-0 mode would have a PW-M0 function. While, the Raspberry Pi Revision 2 schematics show GPIO18 coming out of IC2 is labeled GPIO_Gen1 (sheet 2 of 5) and it is directly wired to header P1 pin 12 and that pad is also labeled GPIO_Gen1 (also sheet 2 of 5). So I am confused as to which is correct.
3. The other possibility is that all pins default to GPIO mode when the board powers-up and to attain the special functions like, UART, I2C and SPI then each respective pin must be set to its respective alternate function mode.

Comment: Might get a better answer over here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/